# Does Kafka use Single Leader or Multi Leader replciation in case of Geo-Replication

Tags: apache-kafka

From what I understand, Kafka use single leader replication. But does this remain same with Geo-Replication switched on ?

Comment: It depends on the chosen method. Have a look at https://www.slideshare.net/HostedbyConfluent/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-apache-kafka-georeplication-with-sanjana-kaundinya-and-rajini-sivaram-kafka-summit-london-2022

Comment: Kafka does have any such switch. Please clarify your question. Are you referring to Confluent **Cloud**? That is not the same as plain Apache Kafka deployment.